# tee diverter / valve to my shower

Tags: plumbing, shower, diverter

I need to attach some kind of tee diverter / valve to my shower. It would look something like this:

[image]

This thing will have 2 outlets. My usual shower head will go on one of the outlets, and the other outlet will have this tube:

[Sioux Chief - 900-01163C00201 - 42143620 - VINYL TUBE 3/8 ID X 1/2 OD (1/16 WALL) CLEAR 20FT COIL](http://Sioux%20Chief%20-%20900-01163C00201%20-%2042143620%20-%20VINYL%20TUBE%203/8%20ID%20X%201/2%20OD%20(1/16%20WALL)%20CLEAR%2020FT%20COIL)

Tube details:

- Internal diameter: 3/8"
- External diameter: 1/2"
- material: transparent vinyl (easily bendable material)

Pictures of the tube:

[image]

[image]

---

While there are plenty tees / diverters available for attaching a hand-shower, I couldn't find anything for my specific tube. So, I'm going to need a couple of adapters. So I'm thinking:

1. a regular hand-shower tee / diverter attachment (1/2" female threaded x two 1/2" males threaded like in first pic).
2. and additionally a 1/2" female threaded x 3/8" hose barb. (Still haven't found this one though.)

If you have suggestions / advice / warnings about how to connect the tube to the shower (in a way that the shower continues to function on demand), I'd appreciate anything.

Comment: Hose barb fittings are very common in homebrewing and can be found in most hardware stores (midwest US, anyway).

Comment: Seems like you have it all figured out -- is this just a shopping question? Female-threaded adapters to hose barb seem to be uncommon. So use one with a male thread and add a threaded coupler.

Comment: @GregHill Thank you. Exactly the kind of advice I was looking for because I haven't actually checked to see if the things I'm planning to use are actually available for sale.

Comment: By the way , the diverter will not shut of  tightly , there will always be a slow drip while the water is on . I was told at Home Depot that is a legal requirement.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Very interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A 1/2" FIP x 3/8" barb is a very common fitting and should be available at any decent plumbing shop or even from the ubiquitous online seller with free shipping: [Anderson Metals - 57002-0608 Brass Hose Fitting, Connector, 3/8" Barb x 1/2" Female Pipe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0045LKB4A)

[image]